# async delegate new form

Tags: c#, forms, delegates

here code

```
delegate void CheckNewsDelegate();

void CheckNews()
{            
    frmNews news = new frmNews();
    news.Show();            
}

CheckNewsDelegate dlg = new CheckNewsDelegate(CheckNews);
dlg.BeginInvoke(null, null);
```

new form not create normal. how fix it?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "not create normal" -- nothing happens, something happens but it's not what you expect...?

Comment: Can you be more specific of what the problem with the form is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, but need to start an application message queue on the other thread.  Replace the CheckNews function with

```
void CheckNews()
{            
    frmNews news = new frmNews();
    Application.Run(news);         
}
```